# Can't add service reference to my project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I have a solution which contains :

```
- a website hosted on my local IIS

- a project that defines a WCF web service

- 2 other projects which are assemblies used by the website
```

I added a console application to quickly test the webservice but when I right click on the project, context menu doesn't contains the "add service reference" entry (but it's present when I right click on the website).

I had done this in the past without problem, why doesn't it work anymore ?

Edit :
If I create a new console project in an empty solution, I can add a service reference.

Comment: If you mean the top main caption in the Solution Explorer like `Solution '.....' (1 Project)` by  saying _when I right click on the project_ , that's normal. There's no _Add Reference_ there.

Comment: Can you try right click to References of console app?

Comment: I mean  when I right click on "myProject" caption not the "solution...", and it's the same when I right click on the References folder of my project.

Comment: Check the version of .Net the project is targeting.  Is it a Client Profile?  You can find this in the first page of the project properties.

Comment: Target Framework is 3.5 full.